# Codeigniter API doesn't respond when sent notification in bulk using laravel admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, codeigniter, cpanel

I have two services on my cpanel, godaddy. One is API which has been developed in Codeigniter another is Admin Panel which is developed in Laravel. *Both share same mysql database.*
 API is used to provide information for android and iOS devices.

> Whenever I send notification from laravel, API doesn't respond.

When I send notifications to user, *the number is around 10k+*, ntofication is also saved for every user in notification table.
I thought maybe that's why it doesn't respond and unable to handle both requests: from api to return query responses and saving notification in database.
It's not the case because I commented out the code that saves the notifications in database yet api calls are not being responded. 
I also tried queuing the notifications saving in the database using laravel queues and redis too, but It didn't help.
 

Now I am confused and I can't figure out where the actual problem is. 
**Is there problem with the server; processing so many requests at the same time?**
**Can using queuing for sending notifications will help the issue? (Not the queuing saving in database process.**)
Below is the server configuration :

> 4 CPU Cores
>   8GB Ram
>   200GB Disk Space
>   CetOS
>   Apache v2.4.39
>   PHP v7.0.33
>   MySQL v5.6.44

Please someone help, I will highly appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: check if the api is working fine or if it has errors. You can use postman to check the API

Comment: I checked, It works fine. I used postman. Also many android and iOS devices are using same API data. It works fine. Problem happens, if I send notifications in bulk.

Comment: are you getting any error or information which are useful to debug.?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't get any error. It's just get stuck when I make api calls. Response comes in that process, but takes too logn.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a beanstalk application that receives the 10k tasks and send the notification 1 by 1 with a worker to the api ?

Either the api is not able to handle all those requests at the same time, or you are not handling good the request to receive them and process it.

Can you give us an example of the request? Does the try/catch give you any reference?

If you give more information I will be pleased to help.

Comment: How can I get a catch block if I get the api response? It's just come so late, when Isending notification is in process.